# Capturar com regex determinada parte da string

Tags: regex

Nesta frase, `/comprar/volkswagen/gol/11184529`, gostaria de capturar se existe a palavra `comprar` o que vem em seguida sem as `/`, ou seja, gostaria de capturar a palavra `volkswagen` (mas poderia ser outra marca(teria que ser genérico, pois não vou adivinhar qual marca)) e `gol` (mas poderia ser outro modelo(teria que ser genérico, pois não vou adivinhar qual marca))

Comment: Regex `^\/comprar\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/\d+$`. Dai pega o primeiro e segundo grupos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex `^\/comprar\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/\d+$`. Daí pegue o primeiro e o segundo grupo.

Tire `^` e `$` caso não for apenas uma ocorrência por linha.

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado

Comment: então, quero pegar todos os parametros apos o dominio `http://www.valeautoshopping.com.br/comprar/volkswagen/gol/11184529`, como faria? Alias o dominio tambem pode ser outro

Comment: Só usar a lógica do regex que eu mostrei: `\/` para a barra, `([^\/]+)` para o grupo que você quer capturar.

Comment: se eu tiver uns 30 parametros, tenho que repetir 30 vezes?
exemplo https://regex101.com/r/kz2ER9/2, mas ele sempre me retorna como `grupo 1` para cada vez que acha e me retorna no js apenas o `http` e `http:`

Comment: Faça `https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/` e depois repita quantos `([^\/]+)` e `\/` forem os parâmetros e as barras, respectivamente, e pegue o grupo de acordo com a sua necessidade (não precisa ser exatamente o primeiro e o segundo só porque eu disse).